# How to determine how much does a download long using PHP?

Tags: php, time, download

I've uploaded a same file on 2 servers in different geographical positions and now, I want to calculate the needed time to download them separately using PHP. Is there any solution for it?
For example I need to have something like this:

> Your download will long about 30 sec. from server #1, and 50 sec from server #2.

Comment: The difference will be very minimal based purely on server latency. There might be a larger difference if one server is experiencing more load than the other, but I doubt you can calculate that.

Comment: You cannot accurately predict download speeds of clients unless you have previous benchmark data.

Comment: Let the client download a small test file to guesstimate their bandwidth.

Comment: you could try to write a small ajax based app, that downloads a 1M File from your servers and estimate the download speed

Comment: @xbonez, imagine that both of servers are the same. Is there any solution to calculate the distance between the client computer and the servers?

Comment: @CodeCaster and reox, how can I do it after this test? do you have any suggested code or function in PHP?

Comment: @MohammadSaberi: You can use a geolocation service to get the user's location based on their IP address, and then approximate their distance from the server. But increased distance only means increased latency, and that alone will cause a very minimal difference in download time (think 30 sec, and 32 sec.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially trying to write a Content Distribution Network (CSN) by the sound of what you're doing.

CDNs are extremely complicated by nature, and use several strategies to determine the shortest path for delivering data.

A simple server side way to achieve this way may be to geolocate the user using the IP address allowing you to determine country or city the user is in. You can then redirect the user to the server nearest their location.

If you want to calculate the time from several servers, you can achieve this by downloading a small file from both servers using the client and using the transfer time to calculate bandwidth.

**Calculating time using AJAX**

I'm assuming you're using jquery but you could easily do this with prototypeJS etc.

```
var date = new Date();
var startTime = date.getMilliseconds();

//Known file size in KB
var fileSize = 100;

$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.example.com"
}).done(function() { 
    alert(calculateBandwidth());
});

function calculateBandwidth(){
    var date = new Date();
    var end = date.getMilliseconds();
    var secondsTaken = (end - start)/1000;
    var KBps = fileSize/secondsTaken;
    return KBps;
}
```

Note this is Kilobytes per seconds. Kilobits would be (filesize*8)/secondsTaken

Comment: Thank you Paul for your answer. You are right. I want to make my own CDN as a university project. Your first solution seems so good, but may you talk more about how can I calculate bandwidth in your 2nd solution?

Comment: What you could do is fire off a request to several severs to retrieve a file of a known size using AJAX. Before each request, not the start time for each server, then after the request completes, note the end time. I'll create an example above.

Comment: Thank you all, specially dear Paul for your posts and comments.